# initWithString and stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding breaks URL iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Trying to create a URL, to open in the iOS browser like so:

```
NSString *urlStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://example.com/#location,data={longitude:%f,latitude:%f}", self.map.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude, self.map.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[urlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

However, this opens the URL as http://example.com/%23location,data=%7Blongitude:-1.938274,latitude:52.079151%7D, which breaks  the URL loading in the browser. Is there anything I can do to mitigate this? ie. encode it in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Why are you using `+stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` in the first place? I don't think there's anything in that URL that needs to be escaped. Just omit that call.</strike>

In general, you can't percent-escape entire URL strings. URL strings have structure. Different characters are legal in different components. You need to compose a URL from it components and percent-escape each component with the proper set of allowed and disallowed characters.

If you can target iOS 7 and later, I recommend that you use `NSURLComponents` to construct your URL:

```
NSURLComponents* components = [[NSURLComponents alloc] init];
components.scheme = @"http";
components.host = @"example.com";
components.path = @"/";
components.fragment = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"location,data={longitude:%f,latitude:%f}", self.map.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude, self.map.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude];
NSURL* url = components.URL;
```

If you can't target just iOS7+, you should just percent-escape the fragment before joining it with the result of URL:

```
NSString* fragment = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"location,data={longitude:%f,latitude:%f}", self.map.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude, self.map.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude];
fragment = [fragment stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString* urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://example.com/#%@", fragment];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlStr];
```

Comment: If I omit it, the last line has no effect (ie. the browser doesn't open), I think it makes `initWithString` return nil

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I normally use this in a separate class in my applications, and it's worked for me.

```
+(NSString *)urlEncodedStringUsingString:(NSString *)string {

    NSString *escapedString = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)string, NULL, CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]\" "), kCFStringEncodingUTF8));

    return escapedString;
}
```